# How to remove concrete slab

Tags: concrete, slab, removal

I have this concrete slab at the front of my house which I want to remove. The slab has 2 air brick holes in it too. These are surrounded by bricks with cement on to give a rounded look and then painted. They are obviously like that because the surface of that slab is higher than the air bricks on the side of the house.

I guess I have 2 options

1. remove the slab and keep the airbrick hole / protectors in place, or
2. remove the slab and the airbrick holes and lower the level of the earth underneath the slab so that it does not enter the airbricks.

How do I remove the slab? Sledgehammer? Anything I should be aware of before I do so? Any other options apart from 1 or 2?

[image: concrete slab]

Answer (score 1):

Sledgehammer will work, but it is way too hard work. Use [hammer drill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hammer_drill) instead.

These drills usually have three or four modes of operation:

1. Drill Like normal drill, usually with higher torque
2. Hammer drill. Drill with additional hammering for drilling through concrete, stone etc.
3. Fixed hammer. The head is locked in rotation and the tool is just ramming.
4. Free hammer. same as 3 but the head rotates freely.

Option 3. is for you. Works like sledgehammer but it is much faster and much easier to do the job. You can lend it at some DIY stores for a good money.

Answer (score 1):

That slab looks really thin the way it has chipped at the edge. I few good hits with a sledgehammer will probably take it out with a few hits. If the concrete is sticking to the air bricks you may need to drill some holes to keep from breaking the bricks, I use an air chizzle to remove mortar from bricks this works well if you have an air compressor, an inexpensive air chizzle can be found for ~30$ with flat,round point and cutting bits. What to be aware of , flying rock chips, wear safety glasses and use heavy gloves the pieces can be very sharp.

Answer (score 0):

Rent an electric jackhammer. You'll thank me.